# Book where a female mage is offered as a sacrifice to a demon, who decides to kill the summoner instead and give her powers

Tags: story-identification, books

A girl mage is captured and is being sacrificed to get a familiar demon but the demon (or something) is too strong and kills the summoner and likes the girls attitude so gives her some powers (shifting for one) and dumped to survive in the elf forest. Meets an elf with a troll fetish

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This could really use more details.  When and where did you read this?  Is this a novel or a manga?  And what does "kills the son inner" mean?

Comment: "kills the summoner" maybe?

Comment: Troll fetish, aka bridge fever.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.